# Why did a WordPress plugin vanish from the WordPress repository?

Tags: plugins

An old client just contacted to find out why his plugin vanished from the WordPress Plugins repository. I was able to find it's [review page](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/dmca-watermarker) but nothing else.

Do you know why the plugin might have disappeared?

Comment: What doe you mean by "his" plugin? A plugin he created or one he was using?

Answer (score 0):

The common case of plugins seemingly going poof is lack of updates for >2 years, which makes them de-listed from search.

In this case however plugin is clearly missing. This is either technical glitch of some kind (not too likely) or it had been removed from repository. The usual reasons are security vulnerabilities and license violations, however there is no way to tell without first hand info from person who removed it.

The channel to inquire would probably be plugins@wordpress.org